# Does $P/O(1)$ equal to $P$ if solver needs to consider smaller inputs?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes

Suppose that $F$ is a problem such that for every $n$, there is a program of length $O(1)$, running in polynomial time to $n$, that solves $F$ correctly on all instances of size less than $n$. Can $F$ be solved in polynomial time? That is, does there exist a *single* polynomial time algorithm that solves $F$ on *all* instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\{P_i\}$ be the limits of programs, or to say, programs that appear for infinte times, then all of them solve $F$, and for each $size(x)$ at least one solve in $P$.

Now run all of them and use the eariest result, and we get a solution in $P$.

Comment: This idea (reminiscent of Levin's optimal algorithm) only works if you can verify solution. Otherwise, it could be that $P_i$ solves the problem correctly, and $P_j$ runs $P_i$ and then negates the result.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Since $P_j$ appears for infinite times, it solves correctly when size is smaller than a large $n$, so it solves this size correctly, but just maybe slow

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "run all of them"?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Run all $P_i$s in the same time. Can be simulated in $P$

Comment: What do you mean by “all $P_i$”?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus `Let {Pi} be the limits of programs`

Comment: It suffices to take a single program that appears infinitely often.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus That may just don't fall in $P$

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $F$ is a problem such that for every $n$, there is a program of length at most $C$, running in polynomial time, that solves $F$ correctly on all instances of size less than $n$.

Let $P_n$ be a program of length at most $C$, running in polynomial time, that solves $F$ correctly on all instances of size less than $n$. Since there are only finitely many programs of length at most $C$, there must be a single program $P$ that occurs infinitely often as $P_n$. This program solves $F$ in polynomial time for *all* instances.

---

If we change $O(1)$ to *any* bound $f(n) = \omega(1)$ computable in $\mathit{poly}(n)$ time, then we can easily construct undecidable problems which are computable in this model. We can assume that $f$ is monotone and has no jumps (otherwise take $g(n) = \min(\max(f(0),\ldots,f(n)),g(n-1)+1)$). For an undecidable $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, consider the following language:
$$
L = \{ x \in \{0,1\}^* : f(|x|) \in S \}.
$$
Since $f$ is monotone, if $|x| \leq n$ then $f(|x|) \leq f(n)$. Hence there is a program of length $f(n) + O(1)$ that solves $L$ correctly on inputs of length at most $n$. Conversely, since $f$ has no jumps, for each $m$ we can find a value $n$ such that $f(n) = m$, and this gives a computable reduction from $S$ to $L$, showing that $L$ is uncomputable.

Comment: Nice! What is the largest advice bound for which this argument still works (i.e. there literally "aren't enough programs" to avoid having some program occur infinitely often)? Does it work for any $\mathbf{P}/o(\log n)$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does work for $\mathbf{P}/o(\log n)$. The number of possible programs for $P_n$ is $2^{o(\log n)}$. For any $k$, we have $2^{o(\log n)} < n/k$ for sufficiently large $n$. So for any $k$, there exists an $n$ such that there is some $P$ where at least $k$ positions $i < n$ have $P_i = P$. This implies that some $P$ occurs infinitely often.

Comment: I don't think so. See my updated answer.

Comment: I'm looking at your proof that it doesn't work and my proof that it does work and they both look right. That probably means mine is wrong, but I don't see why. 

Comment: In your argument, I don't see how you get that some $P$ occurs infinitely often.

Comment: Ahhh, I think I see where that goes wrong. My proof only shows that, for any $k$, there is some program that occurs at least $k$ times in $P$. You could have e.g. an infinite sequence of programs $p_1, p_2, \dots$ where $p_1$ occurs once in $P$, $p_2$ occurs twice in $P$, etc. but no program occurs infinitely often in $P$.

Comment: You edited the question to make it different. I mean $Poly(n)$, not $Poly(size(x))$, so `(with a larger n it still solves well, but maybe slower)`. I thought few hours ago(but without computer to chat here) that, do $f(g(x))$ where $g$ increases slow enough and $f$ costs lots of time, making $f(g(x))$ exponential time to $x$ and $f(g(x)-1)$ polynomial time to $x$, work?

Comment: Your proof works for $R/O(1)$ as input size doesn't matter for $R$, though. Now just lack that $R/f$ where $f$ is uncomputably slow increasing function

Comment: Fotgot that storing the spacial case we store also cost $\omega(1)$ code, so my word was wrong